# Pass prompted variable in Jquery to Flask

Tags: jquery, flask

I am displaying an order that user must approve or reject.
If they reject it, i ask for the reason of the rejection and I want to pass that value to my flask view function.

The HTML for the rejection button:

```
<a id=Rejection href="{{ url_for('main.order_management', order_id=order.id, action='toReject' ) }}">
   <button id="motivo" name="motivo" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 50px" > Reject </button>
</a>
```

The Jquery to get the reason:

```
  $('#Rejection').on('click', function () {
            var reason = prompt("Motivo del Rechazo: ");
            $("#motivo").val(reason);
 
            
        });
```

And the view function:

```
@bp.route('/orden/gestion/<order_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def order_management(order_id):
    accion = request.args.get('action')
     if accion == 'toReject':
           flash('Motivo: {}'.format(request.form.get('motivo')))
           // Do something
```

How can i pass the value pf the prompted variable in the Jquery to my Flask?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to use the information given to show a path that both meets your requirements and is goal-oriented.
I'm not sure you got the right approach. Nevertheless, in the following I will try to provide you with a possible solution based on your code.

```
@bp.route('/order/manage/<int:order_id>', methods=['POST'])
def order_management(order_id):
    action = request.args.get('action')
    if action == 'reject':
        reason = request.form.get('reason')
        # Your code here!
        return make_response('')
    abort(400)
```

This variant uses asynchronous javascript (AJAX). Thus, the behavior on receiving the reaction must be implemented. The browser has no standard behavior for this.

```
<a id="rejection-{{order.id}}" href="{{ url_for('main.order_management', order_id=order.id, action='reject') }}">Reject</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Wait for the content to load.
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // For every anchor with an id that starts with 'rejection' ...
    $("a[id^='rejection']").each(function() {
      // ... register a listener for a click event.
      $(this).click(function(event) {
        // Prevent the standard behavior.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Ask the user for input and return after canceling.
        let reason = prompt("Reason to reject:");
        if (reason === null) return;

        // Send the data as a form using an ajax post request.
        $.post(this.href, { "reason": reason })
          .done(function() {
            // The transfer was successful.
            console.log("Finished rejection");
          });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

A simple alternative to transfer the data with a form without using asynchronous javascript (AJAX) is the following.

```
<form
  name="rejection-{{order.id}}"
  action="{{ url_for('main.order_management', order_id=order.id, action='reject') }}"
  method="POST"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="reason" />
  <button type="submit">Reject</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Wait for the content to load.
$(document).ready(function() {
  // For every form with a name that starts with 'rejection' ...
  $("form[name^='rejection']").each(function() {
    // ... register a listener for a submit event.
    $(this).submit(function(event) {
      // Prevent the standard behavior.
      event.preventDefault();

      // Ask the user for input and return after canceling.
      let reason = prompt("Reason to reject:");
      if (reason === null) return;

      // Set the value of the form field and submit the form.
      this.reason.value = reason;
      this.submit();
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Maybe it helps you. Have fun.